# Will Closures be supported in the final JDK 7 or not?

Tags: java, java-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closures in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233579/closures-in-java-7)

There are so many articles and web pages about Closures in JDK 7. As i remember, first they said that Closures will be in JDK7, then they said that they won't be - but that was in the beginning of 2009. Then in the end of 2009 they said that they will be in JDK7 again. Now as i'm researching this issue, i'm a bit confused and i just can't find a definite, absolutely final statement for this.

I found out that Closures are now under the hood of [Project Lambda](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/), but not if it will be included in the final JDK (i only read "proposal", "eventual" etc.)

As i'm currently writing a thesis where i want to tell if Closures are supported in JDK 7 i need to be completely sure and i also need a good source for this information (as new as possible, possibly from someone from the JDK staff or so).

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233579/closures-in-java-7

Comment: This question was asked 2008. Most answers are also 2008 or 2009. Now it's mid of 2010. As the JDK-devs changed their mind so often, i'm asking this question again to now if they changed their mind again. And i need a good and recent web page as a proof.

Comment: "They"? The JSR expert group has not been formed yet - http://jcp.org

Comment: @ifischer: There's a reason why questions and answers are editable Wikis. That way, there will only ever be *one* instance of every question and it will always be up to date.

Comment: We aren't still calling these things "closures", are we?  I thought there'd been a switch to the more appropriate "lambdas".

Comment: You can't find a definite, absolutely final statement for this because there isn't one.

Comment: I think it's pretty ridiculous to close a question in favor of one two years old that has information that isn't even close to current or relevant, all in the name of this illusion of well maintained definitive answers to questions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think there is any absolute answer to your question right now. JDK 7 may or may not have lambdas. Work is in progress and there has been quite a bit of activity on the project-lambda mailing list, but I don't think Oracle is saying anything right now about the schedule or whether or not project-lambda will be included. It still has a long ways to go and a lot of design issues to be worked out, I think.

You should follow the [lambda-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/lambda-dev) mailing list and check its archives if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely expect `'Closures will be included in JDK 7'` because among 8 milestones for this release [Milestone 6](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/m6/changes/) has been included Closures. Project Lambda also got [approved](http://openjdk.java.net/).

When Milestone 6 has included Closures, we can surely expect it will be with JDK 7

Comment: Sorry, but M6 does not include lambdas and there's nothing guaranteeing that JDK 7 will have them either. Work is in progress on a fork, that's all.