# Pass Function with Parameter-Defined Behavior in Java

Tags: java, function, lambda, parameter-passing, function-pointers

In Java, I want to define a normalizing function that takes *one number* as input but whose behavior is defined by *multiple parameters*.

Essentially, the Java equivalent of this in Lisp:

```
(define (normalizeVal min max floor ceiling)
  (lambda (x) (/ (* (- ceiling floor) (- x min)) (+ (- max min) floor))))
```

In pseudo-code, I'd like to:

```
function parsing(data, normalizeValFunc) {
   for (datum in data):
      normalizeValFunc(datum);
}

var input = userData;
var min, max, floor, ceiling = /* Calculate min, max, floor, and ceiling */
var output = parsing(input, normalizeValFunc(min, max, floor, ceiling));
```

Passing functions as parameters in Java can be tricky because functions are not first class objects in Java. (Maybe Java 8 Lambda expressions changes this?) Other questions address the issue of passing functions as parameters in Java, such as [How to pass a function as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java), [What's the nearest substitute for a function pointer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122407/whats-the-nearest-substitute-for-a-function-pointer-in-java), and [Function Pointers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073358/function-pointers-in-java)

However, none of these questions concern passing a function whose behavior is defined by parameters other than the function's input value. I don't know in advance what the min, max, floor, and ceiling parameters of the normalization function will be, but I only want the effective normalizing function to take one argument, the value to be normalized.

Comment: take a look at Guava Functions https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Comment: Nice reference. Would upvote you if I had enough reputation.

Comment: You need closures. Lambdas make it easy, but unfortunately anonymous class route is the only way in pre-Java 8. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443510/closure-in-java-7), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233579/closures-in-java-7) etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old-fashioned way of doing this is with an interface:

```
public interface Normalizer {
    int normalize(int value);
}
```

You would then create an instance of a `Normalizer`, e.g. with an anonymous class:

```
public static Normalizer normalizeValFunc(final int min, final int max, final int floor, final int ceiling) {
    return new Normalizer() {
        @Override public int normalize(int value) {
            /* Use min, max, floor, ceiling & value here to return something. */
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can write a function that takes a `Normalizer`:

```
void parsing(int[] data, Normalizer normalizer) {
  // Call normalizer.normalize(...)
}
```

And call it like this:

```
parsing(/* something here */, normalizeValFunc(min, max, floor, ceiling))
```

In Java 8, you can avoid the anonymous class and just use a lambda instead:

```
public static normalizeValFunc(final int min, final int max, final int floor, final int ceiling) {
    return value -> /* Use min, max, floor, ceiling & value here to return something. */
}
```

You may as well do this inline:

```
parsing(/* something here */, value -> /* an expression using min, max, floor, ceiling, value */)
```

Also, rather than define a `Normalizer`, you can just use the standard [`IntUnaryOperator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) functional interface (and call `applyAsInt` instead of `normalize`).

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for. I'd upvote you right now if I had enough reputation.